# How do I select this html element in testcafe?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test a react app.  One step of this involves clicking "OK" on a modal that comes up.  I can't seem to select this HTML element no matter what I do and would appreciate some help.

```
import { waitForReact } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';
import { ReactSelector } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';

fixture `App tests`
    .page('http://localhost:3000/')
    .beforeEach(async () => {
        await waitForReact();
    });

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
        .click('#LayerAddingPopUpButtonID'); //works correctly and opens modal

    await t.click(".ant-btn");
});
```

When I run my test, it is in the state "waiting for an element to appear" until it fails.

I'm trying to select the element "html body div div div.ant-modal-wrap div.ant-modal div.ant-modal-content div.ant-modal-footer div button.ant-btn.ant-btn-primary"

My rendered page looks like this (with the selected element being the one I want to access):
[image]